# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Having issues with Schedule API

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get my bot to send a message periodically, but am having some issues. Here's my code:

```
def job():
    channel = client.get_channel(806740247009296445)
    await channel.send("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I try this, it gives me an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the line with `await channel.send`. I also tried using `await ctx.channel.send`, but that tells me `TypeError: job() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`.

I am not sure  why this is happening, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. The invalid syntax error is because you can only use the `await` keyword inside another coroutines, the `job` function is a normal, sync function, not a coroutine
2. If you even make the `job` a coroutine you'll also have to `await` it, and as I said before, you can only await inside another coroutines
3. You're using blocking code, the schedule module is blocking, same as `time.sleep`

The easiest approach to fix all errors at once would be to use the discord.py extension `tasks`

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def job():
    channel = client.get_channel(806740247009296445)
    await channel.send("I'm working...")

job.start()
```

Comment: Although this would work, I also want to schedule for it to do something every day at a certain time. If I restart the code, it also restarts the loop.

Comment: discord.py 1.7 allows you pass a datetime object directly to the decorator, you can either wait till it's released or install it directly from github, [PR link](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/6456) if you want to check it out